# Shockley equation of an E-MOSFET with a B instead of a K

Tags: mosfet, jfet, equation

I have a question about the following homework exercise.

I have no clue what B means in this equation. I could not find meaning of it in google nor in the books.

[image]

Could someone link me a resource or explain what B means here and what it's unit is?

Comment: Is it B they are referring to or just Beta ?? You should check for the classic J-FET formula that has the form given as : Id = Idss[ 1 - Vgs/Vp ]^2 then rearrange to obtain the factor Beta as a function of Idss, Vp etc...

Comment: @citizen it's jsut Beta, but i have no clue what kind of Beta. They changed K with Beta and swapped Vgs and VP from original euqation for some reason.

Comment: It is more of an algebra test than actual physics. They just want you to find the expression for beta as it is written above, nothing more. I guess the following questions (that you have not posted) may go deeper into the J-FET workings ... Just do the algebra and get the Beta as a function of Idss and Vp as what is generally used in the classic equation. Look up the classic equation that is usually given in the format I already quoted, and get the two equations to be the same, then you will have an answer for Beta as it is presented by the examiner.